# Can Anyone Tell Me , Which Insect or I think Moth Is This

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species

[image]

Region : Asia ( India ) , Size is about : 4 cm . Since yesterday this Insect is in the same place . I don't know any other info , I was just curious to know about this Insect.

Comment: This is not a fly! Can you give more information about this individual? Where (what region, what country, what type of ecosystem) did you find it? What is the approximate size? Any behaviour to notice? Did you get a picture where we can see its butt? Any other info?

Comment: But it is deffinitly look interesting.

Comment: Region : Asia ( India ) , Size is about : 4 cm , Since yesterday this Insect is in the same place . I don't know any other info , I was just curious to know about this Insect.